# Laravel passport public api routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am trying to code a login function for my api that takes a username and password then give you a password grant token to make api requests. The login route when called gives you

```
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

I am using passport on laravel to do secure the api. Why am I getting a 401 when the route does not have the auth:api middleware? I tried using a clousure to see if I get could get a response and the closure did not give me an error.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/v1', 'middleware' => ['auth:api'], 'namespace' => 'Api\V1', 'as' => 'api.'], function () {
        Route::post('/post/like','PostLikeController@store');

});
Route::group(['prefix' => '/v1', 'namespace' => 'Api\V1', 'as' => 'api.'], function () {
        Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your login controller have a constructor? sometimes middleware is set in there?

Otherwise I've also had issues with having the middleware routes above the public ones.

Try putting the public routes in the file first and also checking the `LoginController.php` for a constructor which might be setting a middleware

Comment: It does not have a constructor

Comment: Have you tried swapping the routes around? putting public ones first.

Answer (score 0):

It possibly due to the same prefixes, as it does not overriding but instead stacking on top of each other.

I suggest for your login route, possibly, you can use this

```
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->withoutMiddleware([FooMiddleware::class]);
```

If it's still does not help try putting your login route above the middlewared route.